# default zsh alias for dir?

Tags: function, shell, zsh, alias

On a Linux host system the default zsh install provides an alias to 'dir'. It is 'ls -l'.

I cannot find the system startup file that is responsible for setting this alias.

/etc/zsh/* files have nothing related.

The way I found out about the default alias is that I have a zsh shell function defined in my .zshrc, like this:

dir () { ls ... | less ...}

Now, with the default alias this results in ls being defined with ls and the circular reference prevents ls being used at all.

I fixed this by adding 'unalias dir' prior to defining dir().

However, I am still frustrated and wish to find the source of the alias created for dir.

Could you help?

Comment: Your question seems less about zsh and more about your particular system's configuration file locations, but you do not give any hint what system you have.

Comment: Open a new interactive shell with `zsh -lx`  and check the output. You should find the place where the alias is defined.

Comment: To Max Power: Thanks, I edited the question, added the word Linux. I note though that the '/etc/zsh' and the forwards slashes should be a hint regarding the OS type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks user1934428! Using zsh -lx I found the culprit.

The /etc/zprofile sourced /etc/profile which sourced /etc/bash.bashrc which sourced /etc/profile.d/ls.bash, which had the alias definition.

I argue that the zsh shell function definition should ignore aliases on the function name; that almost never could be the right thing to do...

Comment: Alias expansion occurs before command lookup, so this isn't something the shell should police: use aliases at your own risk. A bigger problem is that `/etc/profile` should not be sourcing `/etc/bash.bashrc` without confirming that you are, in fact, using `bash`.

Comment: I agree. But I cannot control the system files on this machine.

And to be precise, I did not talk about command lookup. I talked about function definition which happens once. If zsh sees:

dir () { ls -lat | less }

then using an existing alias for dir does not make sense. The behaviors I consider right are either: discard the alias and define the function or report an error about trying to define a function that has an alias for it.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it doesn't make sense *to you*, it's still legal.